# aiogram FSM и кнопка вернуть назад

Tags: python, aiogram

Я хочу сделать бота который будет добавлять в базу данных информацию про бензин на заправках. У каждой заправки может быть свой список марок горючего. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как мне сделать чтобы я заходил в заправку выбрал например на этой клавиатуре А92 оно бах записало в переменную, потом выбрал А95 записало в переменную...  а потом я говорю ок из 3х вариантов горючего есть только два значит я сохраняю их бд.. и эти две переменные я отдаю в функцию сохранение в бд.

```
from db import db_connect as db
from settings import config
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
from db import db_connect as db


class FSMAdmin(StatesGroup):
    station = State()
    fuel = State()


async def fsm_start(message: types.Message):
    await FSMAdmin.station.set()
    await message.answer("Оберіть заправку", reply_markup=config.STATION_FUEL_MENU, disable_notification=True)


async def cancel_handler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    current_state = await state.get_state()
    if current_state is None:
        return
    await state.finish()
    await message.answer("Відміна команди виконана", reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())


async def back_state():
    await FSMAdmin.previous()


async def set_station(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['station'] = message.text

    stations = {
        '⛽ Shell': config.FUELS_ALL_MENU,
        '⛽ MAC': config.FUELS_BEZ_GAZ,
        '⛽ Belarus': config.FUELS_GAZ_MENU,
    }

    await message.answer("Вкажіть наявність пального",
                         reply_markup=stations[message.text],
                         disable_notification=True)
    await FSMAdmin.next()


async def save_fuel(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    current_state = await state.get_state()
    if current_state is None:
        return
    await db.update_db(state)
    await state.finish()
    await message.answer("Дані успішно збережені", reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())


async def set_fuel(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    dict_fuel = {
        "А-95": "fuel_95",
        "А-92": "fuel_92",
        "ДП": "fuel_dp",
        "Газ": "fuel_gaz"
    }
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data.setdefault("choise_fuel", [])
        if dict_fuel[message.text] not in data["choise_fuel"]:
            data["choise_fuel"].append(dict_fuel[message.text])


def register_handlers_admin(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(fsm_start, commands="пальне", state=None, chat_id=[978284975, 261891285, 145333452])
    dp.register_message_handler(cancel_handler, state="*", commands="відміна")
    dp.register_message_handler(cancel_handler, Text(equals="відміна", ignore_case=True), state="*")
    dp.register_message_handler(back_state, Text(equals="️ Назад", ignore_case=True), state="*")
    dp.register_message_handler(save_fuel, state="*", commands="/Зберегти")
    dp.register_message_handler(save_fuel, Text(equals=" Зберегти", ignore_case=True), state="*")
    dp.register_message_handler(set_station, state=FSMAdmin.station)
    dp.register_message_handler(set_fuel, Text(equals=["А-95", "А-92", "ДП", "Газ"]), state=FSMAdmin.fuel)
```

Comment: при чем тут кнопка назад?

Comment: два в одном. Спросил общую задачу и нужно кнопку назад реализовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного поменял ваш код, но в целом оно теперь будет в стейт записывать выбранный тип топлива.
PS. И да, я не люблю регистрацию хендлеров, ибо фиг поймешь что вообще происходит.

```
class FSMAdmin(StatesGroup):
    station = State()
    set_fuel = State()


# state=None писать бессмысленно, этот фильтр стоит по умолчанию
@dp.message_handler(commands=["пальне"], chat_id=[978284975, 261891285, 145333452])
async def fsm_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Оберіть заправку", 
                         reply_markup=config.STATION_FUEL_MENU, 
                         disable_notification=True)
    await FSMAdmin.station.set()


@dp.message_handler(state="*", commands="відміна")
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals="відміна", ignore_case=True), state="*")
async def cancel_handler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    current_state = await state.get_state()
    if current_state is None:
        return
    await state.finish()
    await message.answer("Відміна команди виконана", 
                         reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())


@dp.message_handler(state=FSMAdmin.station)
async def set_station(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['station'] = message.text

    choise_dict = {
        '⛽ Заправка1': config.FUELS_ALL_MENU,
        '⛽ Заправка2': config.FUELS_BEZ_GAZ,
        '⛽ Заправка3': config.FUELS_GAZ_MENU,
    }

    await message.answer("Вкажіть наявність пального", 
                         reply_markup=choise_dict[message.text],
                         disable_notification=True)
    await FSMAdmin.next()


@dp.message_handler(state="*", commands="/Зберегти")
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals=" Зберегти", ignore_case=True), state="*")
async def save_fuel(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    current_state = await state.get_state()
    if current_state is None:
        return
    await db.update_db(state)
    await state.finish()
    await message.answer("Дані успішно збережені", reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())


@dp.message_handler(text=["А-95", "А-92", "ДП", "Газ"], state=FSMAdmin.set_fuel)
async def set_fuel(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    dict_fuel = {
        "А-95": "fuel_95",
        "А-92": "fuel_92",
        "ДП": "fuel_dp",
        "Газ": "fuel_gaz"
    }
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        # делаем список по-умолчанию
        data.setdefault("choise_fuel", [])
        # если такого элемента нет то добалвляем
        if dict_fuel[message.text] not in data["choise_fuel"]: 
            data["choise_fuel"].append(dict_fuel[message.text])
    # дабавлен какой-то типо топлива в стейт
```

Comment: А если мне не один вид топлива нужен.. а несколько... Тоесть для одной заправки я должен указать несколько значений... Блин как то немного сложно для понимание.

Comment: См. последний хендлер. Обновил. Теперь будет как. Юзер жмакает кнопку, создается пустой список, а потом в него добавляется значение из словаря выше. Если нажмет ещё на одну кнопку то словарь новый не создастся(так как уже есть) и просто добавиться новое значение в список. Теперь только в бд код поменяй у тебя в `data["choise_fuel"]` будет список строк. Если есть вопросы задавай

Comment: У меня почему то не срабатывает последний хендлер) я поправил код, все таки оставил часть своего... Но я пробывал и полностью ваш... А мы бы не могли связаться в дисе?

Comment: Странно, поставьте принт в хендлер

Comment: ставил. не работает.

Comment: Попробуйте чисто `text="А-95"`, может я провтыкал и нельзя список кидать в него. Ну и на эту кнопку нажмите

Comment: Может я вообще "А" сделал на англ раскладке

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137649/discussion-between-oleksandrigo-and-mserega).